# Installing pandas with Esri's python?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, numpy, pandas

Trying to get pandas to import, but I'm getting what looks like an error caused by a failed dependency of the version of my Esri-provided numpy's compile, based on [this stackoverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709641/valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling). Here's what I get.

```
>>> import pandas
numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "numpy.pxd", line 157, in init pandas.hashtable (pandas\hashtable.c:22315)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

I check my numpy version:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version.full_version
'1.6.1'
```

Based on this, I believe that this is the right version of numpy for the version of pandas I'm using (tried 13.1, 14.0, and 14.1).

I'm running the standard ESRI-shipped python for ArcGIS 10.2 (Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32).

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> arcpy.__file__
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.2\\arcpy\\arcpy\\__init__.py'
```

Has anyone succeeded in getting pandas going this way or have ideas on what's wrong with my environment?

Should I update my numpy, which is supposed to be backwards compatible (according to user333700's text at the bottom of the stackoverflow posting), or is that likely to break my ArcGIS functionality?

Comment: Hey there,  looks like your post is missing the link to the stackoverflow to which you are referring!

Comment: right. sorry. fixed. thx.

Comment: I'm using multiple versions of Python to get around this. I've installed the Anacondas package which is similar to Enthought, but is free. I use a .pth file in both the Anacondas and Arc directories to link libraries. I will try to find a link to a description of the method.

Comment: Here is a link to another stackexchange question that should help you out. I used Rich's method and applied it to my installation of Anacondas: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59012/how-to-access-esri-arcpy-modules-from-enthought-canopy

Comment: Here is another link: http://rsignell.tiddlyspot.com/#%5B%5BUsing%20Pandas%20with%20ESRI%20(via%20Anaconda)%5D%5D

Comment: @Jason thanks. I made that (the tiddlyspot stuff) work. Is this approach (of installing an entirely additional python environment) really necessary to make pandas work w/10.2? (Also, I've been told (by Curtis) that the *.pth thing was unsupported for 10.2).

Comment: I used this method while on 10.1 and am now using it with 10.2. I don't know whether you can get Pandas and Arc to work together without having an additional python environment, but I do know that this method works for me. I use the Anacondas version of Python exclusively and haven't yet run into anything not working correctly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to get pandas working in ArcMap 10.1 using pandas packages already built for Anaconda.

One of the nice things about Anaconda (besides being free) is that it's easy to create environments with specific versions of python and numpy.

Try this:

Open a 32-bit Anaconda command prompt and type:

```
conda create -n esri101 python=2.7 numpy=1.6 pandas
activate esri101
```

Then create a file called `conda.pth` in your ArcGIS10.1 site-packages folder.  On my machine this is `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\conda.pth`

In this file add one line that points to your Anaconda site-packages for the `esri101` environment you created.  On my machine this is:

```
C:\programs\Anaconda\envs\esri101\Lib\site-packages
```

Then fire up ArcMap and try `import pandas`.

The only unfortunate thing is that it looks like the latest pandas release anyone built for windows with `python=2.7` and `numpy=1.6` is `pandas=0.10.1`.  I might try building a later version using [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285317/panda-versions-compatible-with-specific-python-and-numpy-configurations)

Comment: Let us know if you have success building a newer version.

Comment: Did this for Arc 10.3 (python=2.7.8 numpy=1.7.1) and it built using pandas 0.13.0. Worked great, finally have pandas working in arcpy, thank you!!!

Comment: For the one line in conda.pth, do you just need the file location or should it be prefaced by something like %PATH%?  -- not a windows user

Comment: What if you create the environment, and then realize that a package is missing? Such as `netcdf4`... can I install it *inside* the environment I have just created?