# Installing pandas for use with ArcPy in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, installation, pandas

I followed the very clear directions in the [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/110563/115) to [Installing pandas with Esri's python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110425/installing-pandas-with-esris-python) and created the Esri101 build and added a "conda.pth" file to my C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\conda.pth

and in the conda.pth file I pasted the location of my Esri101 build with no quotes
When I open ArcMap or the Python27 IDLE and type ">>> import pandas" I get the resulting error:

```
DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
   import pandas
 File "C:\Anaconda\envs\esri101\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Quick check online makes me think this might have something to do with running a 64-bit anaconda and a 32 bit ArcGIS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not figure out how to get the Anaconda to link to ArcMap Python27, I think I need to add a second 32 bit version of Anaconda but don't want to mess with my 64-bit Anaconda install.

I did get pandas installed on the ArcGIS python27 (2.7.5) that comes with Arcmap 10.2.2

**First:**
I modified my system variables temporarily to make the Arcgis Python be the default.
In Right Click Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variables

I removed the default Anaconda path (saving it in a text file for later) which looked like this
*C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Scripts;*
I then added  this path 
*C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Scripts;*

Go to terminal, double check that when you enter python it says python 2.7.5.

**Second:**
Then I needed to install [setup_tools](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html) for this version of python.

**Third:**
Then in the command prompt I entered >> easy_install pandas==0.10.1 (the current version failed when I tried to install it)

Check if "import pandas" works in IDLE 2.7.5 , IT DID!

**Finally:**
I changed my python system path back to the original Anaconda path (I use Spyder and Anaconda independently of Arcmap often, so this was important for me).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure when this was added but I just tested importing pandas into the IDLE that gets installed as part of ArcGIS Desktop 10.6, and it looks like pandas is now part of the standard install.

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import arcpy
>>> import pandas
>>>
```