# integrating arcpy with other packages

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-2.7, anaconda

I have the windows installation of python 2.7 that came with arcgis 10.2.  In my linux installation of python, I've become fond of other packages, and I'd like to incorporate them into the windows python.  I went through the steps to install pip, and I've got pip working in c:\python2.7\scripts.  But, each time I try to pip install anything (run from that Scripts directory), it fails (with various errors, mostly not finding certain files).

On the other hand, I've used package managers like Canopy or Anaconda, but I don't know how to get arcpy into one of those.

I surely don't quite have the hang of site-packages, dist-packages, paths and environments, particularly in Windows.

Has anyone done this successfully, and can you summarize your steps?

Comment: Also related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110425/installing-pandas-with-esris-python

Answer (score 4):

I went with simply installing the manager pip-Win. It will install pip and virtualenv for you.
Then it can identify your python installations (or you can browse to a specific python.exe to add more) and take care of all of your pip execution and package maintenance.

https://sites.google.com/site/pydatalog/python/pip-for-windows

Very important warning: Don't upgrade numpy on your ArcGIS python install. This tends to break things in arcpy.

Comment: I agree on the note about Numpy. Additionally, some packages that depend on Numpy (Pandas in my case) will not work with the specialized/modified version of Numpy packaged with ArcPy (at ArcGIS 10.2) - I have no clue why.

Comment: Thanks, I will go give it a try.  Which directory did you install it into?

Comment: pip-Win is not really an installer. It looks like one, but you just execute the installer as an application each time you use it. So I just keep a copy on my desktop for when I need it.

Comment: Oh, hey -- warning to future readers -- running those pip-Win instructions as written in the link starts off by trying to upgrade numpy!

Comment: Still no winner.  It throws the very same errors.  You know, I think it might be the non-standard numpy.  Both modules I wanted rely on it.

Comment: Yes, the non-standard numpy will break things every time. If you are trying to use the latest matplotlib, rasterio or GDAL, you are going to have problems.