# Using pandas in Python window of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, pandas, python-window

How can I import pandas module in ArcGIS at figure. I want to calculate poisson and negative binomial, so I think I need import pandas or other modules.

```
import pandas as pd
       Runtime error 
       Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
       ImportError: No module named pandas

import numpy as np
   from scipy.stats import nbinom
   def _ll_nb2(y, X, beta, alph):
   mu = np.exp(np.dot(X, beta))
   size = 1 / alph
   prob = size / (size + mu)
   ll = nbinom.logpmf(y, size, prob)
   return ll

 Runtime error 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
 File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 338, in     <module>
 from .stats import *
 File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 184, in    <module>
 import scipy.special as special
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 593, in <module>
 from ._ellip_harm import ellip_harm, ellip_harm_2, ellip_normal
 File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\_ellip_harm.py", line 7, in <module>
  from ._ellip_harm_2 import _ellipsoid, _ellipsoid_norm
 File "_ellip_harm_2.pyx", line 2, in init scipy.special._ellip_harm_2    (scipy\special\_ellip_harm_2.c:7480)
File "C:\Users\erdogan\Anaconda\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
 ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 not proper for Win32 application.
```

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to include the text (perhaps as well as the picture) of the code you are running and the error you see, please?

Comment: Just do not update Arc's numpy.  There is a good discussion with solutions here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110425/installing-pandas-with-esris-python.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641199

Below steps worked for me(Windows8.1)

Install [it](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)

Configure pip [a way to configure pip](http://arunrocks.com/guide-to-install-python-or-pip-on-windows/)

Go to [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas) and install prereqisites (wheel files)

Install panda