# Import pandas from ArcGIS Script Tool

Tags: arcgis-10.1, installation, python-script-tool, pandas

I am developing a data import script tool for ArcGIS that downloads from an SQL Server into a pandas DataFrame. This python script worked perfectly as I built it in Spyder however now that I am setting it up in a Toolbox, ArcGIS cannot import pandas.

I have tried [Installing pandas with Esri's python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110425) on my own however what I am looking to do is automate the process so as soon as the tool is run the script checks for pandas and installs as necessary on any user's machine. I already fixed this similar problem with pypyodbc by storing the necessary setup scripts in the public drive folder where the tool script is located:

```
import os
import imp
path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
path = path[:-16]
os.chdir(path)
try:
    imp.find_module('pypyodbc')
    found = True
except ImportError:
    found = False
if found == False:
        import setup
        import pypyodbc
```

I can't seem to apply this method to pandas as there isn't an install/setup script I can save in my public folder. Is there any way to automate the install of pandas from a Script Tool in ArcGIS?

Comment: To me this sounds like a Python problem that should be asked over at [so].  It sounds like the ArcGIS Script tool is an aside and really you're wanting to know how to install `pandas` from python.  Once you know how to do this you should be able to do it from ArcGIS.

Comment: It's actually, imo, pretty ArcGIS specific as any work around needs to be tailored to the ArcGIS interface and the downloaded instance of Python.